# How to create a monorepo using yarn that contains multiple apps that can only use the root workspaces?

Tags: javascript, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have the following folder structure that I want to make a monorepo using yarn:

```
/root
 /apps
   /app-one
   /app-two
 /packages
   /ui
```

I want that only the `root/packages/*` modules can be used by `apps/*` projects. Meaning I don't want that `apps/app-one` can use a module of `apps/app-two`. `root/apps/*` can only use modules from `root/packages/*`,
So I don't want that `root/node_modules` can possibly contain any module exported from `root/apps/*`.

**The problem is when I do `yarn install` inside `root/apps/app-one` I get the following error:**
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz53z.png)

**I understand that yarn couldn't link that packages to any remote node module or local module using symlink. But how to achieve what I want If it does not support that ?**

**What I did:**
I initialized yarn using `yarn init` inside the `root/` folder. I updated the root `package.json` to the following:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.0.2",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

In `root/packages/ui/`:
1- I did `yarn init`
2- I created a `index.js` file with this content: `export const A = 22;`
3- I changed the `package.json` to:

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.0.2"
}
```

In `root/apps/app-one`:
1- I did `yarn init`
2- I changed the `package.json` to:

```
{
  "name": "app-one",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "ui": "*"
  }
}
```

3- I created a `index.js` file with this content: `import {A} from 'ui'`
4- Following the error message after doing `yarn install` i added an empty `yarn.lock` file for this to be treated as a seperate project.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqoas.png)

Also for the modules to be installed in `node_modules` I added the following `.yarnrc.yml` file inside `root/` and `root/apps/app-one`: `nodeLinker: "node_modules"`

This is the final folder structure:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noL9z.png)